# Can't get rows for zero values in SQL query with COUNT and 3 JOINs (4 tables)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I am trying to get a row for each combination of CELLNAME and LANGUAGE but I can't get rows for zero counts. For example if a CELLNAME 'x' doesn't contain any CLIENT_ID or CLNOCL with language code DE I don't get a row with zero count. This works perfectly when there's one or more of any of the languages.  The database used is Oracle.
I'm stuck on this for a while and as I'm not very good at SQL, I'd appreciate if any one could help. Here's the query:

```
                select QA_ID,MODULE_ID,ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIBUTE_NAME,CELLNAME,CNT

            FROM 

            (SELECT QA_ID,CELLNAME,LANGUE, COUNT(*) CNT 
             FROM (
                                                           select QA_ID,CELLNAME,
                                                                          CASE 
                                                                          WHEN CLOLAN = 'EN' THEN  'ENGLISH' 
                                                                          WHEN CLOLAN = 'DE' THEN 'GERMAN'
                                                                                          ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
                                                                          END as LANGUE    
                                                           from TB_PROP_Q A 

                                                           INNER JOIN VWFC_WKCLIE B
                                                           ON A.CLIENT_ID = B.CLNOCL
                                                           )

            GROUP BY QA_ID,CELLNAME, LANGUE 
            )C
                           INNER JOIN 
                                           (
                                           SELECT A.MODULE_ID,A.MODULE_NAME,B.ATTRIBUTE_NAME,B.ATTRIBUTE_ID
                                           FROM QA_TABLE_MODULE A 
                                           INNER JOIN QA_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE B 
                                           ON A.MODULE_ID=B.MODULE_ID
                                           WHERE MODULE_NAME = 'LANGUE'
                                           )D
            ON C.LANGUE = D.ATTRIBUTE_NAME
```

Comment: You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` in order to get counts where there are zero matching rows. Also `COUNT(*)` won't work in this case - that will return 1 since a null row will be returned in the left outer join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data：

```
TB_PROP_Q 
CLIENT_ID       CELLNAME    QA_ID 
#ABEG20XA69001  MODELE1_C   20150401152337 
#ACQM679487001  MODELE1_C   20150401152337 
#ATTP6AS979801  MODELE1_A   20150401152337 
#AZIP516667001  MODELE1_C   20150401152337 
#ECLJ5YAHA8XX1  MODELE1_C   20150401152337 
#EVAY429382001  MODELE1_B   20150401152337 
#ICOX189625001  MODELE1_B   20150401152337 
#ORXY5A8780001  MODELE1_B   20150401152337 
#RBAH046697001  MODELE1_C   20150401152337 

VWFC_WKCLIE
CLNOCL          CLOLAN  
#ABEG20XA69001  EN  
#ATTP6AS979801  EN 
#ACQM679487001  DE 
#ICOX189625001  DE  
#ALBK048878001  EN  
#ACQM679487001  EN 

QA_TABLE_MODULE 
MODULE_ID       MODULE_NAME 
1               LANGUE  
2               AGE

QA_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE 
ATTRIBUTE_ID    ATTRIBUTE_NAME  MODULE_ID   
1               GERMAN          1   
2               ENGLISH         1   
3               UNKNOWN         1   
4               0_17_YO         2   
5               18_34_YO        2   
6               35_54_YO        2
```

You can calculate the count of languages first and then get CNT by left join it.

```
SELECT QA_ID,MODULE_ID,ATTRIBUTE_ID,ATTRIBUTE_NAME,CELLNAME,CNT
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.QA_ID,A.CELLNAME,B.LANGUE,nvl(C.CNT,0) AS CNT FROM TB_PROP_Q A
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 'ENGLISH' AS LANGUE
        UNION
        SELECT 'GERMAN' AS LANGUE
        UNION
        SELECT 'UNKNOWN' AS LANGUE
    )B ON 1=1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT QA_ID,CELLNAME,LANGUE, COUNT(*) CNT 
        FROM 
        (
           select QA_ID,CELLNAME,
           CASE 
           WHEN CLOLAN = 'EN' THEN 'ENGLISH' 
           WHEN CLOLAN = 'DE' THEN 'GERMAN'
           ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
           END AS LANGUE    
           FROM TB_PROP_Q A 
           INNER JOIN VWFC_WKCLIE B
           ON A.CLIENT_ID = B.CLNOCL
        )A
        GROUP BY QA_ID,CELLNAME,LANGUE 
    )C ON A.QA_ID=C.QA_ID AND A.CELLNAME=C.CELLNAME AND B.LANGUE=C.LANGUE
)C
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT A.MODULE_ID,A.MODULE_NAME,B.ATTRIBUTE_NAME,B.ATTRIBUTE_ID
    FROM QA_TABLE_MODULE A 
    INNER JOIN QA_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE B 
    ON A.MODULE_ID=B.MODULE_ID
    WHERE MODULE_NAME = 'LANGUE'
)D
ON C.LANGUE = D.ATTRIBUTE_NAME
```

Output：

```
QA_ID           CELLNAME    LANGUE  CNT
20150401152337  MODELE1_A   ENGLISH 1
20150401152337  MODELE1_A   GERMAN  0
20150401152337  MODELE1_A   UNKNOWN 0
20150401152337  MODELE1_B   ENGLISH 0
20150401152337  MODELE1_B   GERMAN  1
20150401152337  MODELE1_B   UNKNOWN 0
20150401152337  MODELE1_C   ENGLISH 2
20150401152337  MODELE1_C   GERMAN  1
20150401152337  MODELE1_C   UNKNOWN 0
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to this post. The problem is that CLOLANG is in VWFC_WKCLIE table. 
TB_PROP_Q has these columns: QA_ID, CLIENT_ID and CELLNAME.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? TKS.

Comment: TB_PROP_Q


    CLIENT_ID  CELLNAME QA_ID
 #ABEG20XA69001 MODELE1_C 20150401152337
 #ACQM679487001 MODELE1_C 20150401152337
 #ATTP6AS979801 MODELE1_A 20150401152337
 #AZIP516667001 MODELE1_C 20150401152337
 #ECLJ5YAHA8XX1 MODELE1_C 20150401152337
 #EVAY429382001 MODELE1_B 20150401152337
 #ICOX189625001 MODELE1_B 20150401152337
 #ORXY5A8780001 MODELE1_B  20150401152337
 #RBAH046697001 MODELE1_C 20150401152337

Comment: VWFC_WKCLIE:CLNOCL   CLOLAN  
 #ABEG20XA69001 EN   
 #ATTP6AS979801 EN    
 #ACQM679487001 DE   
 #ICOX189625001 DE   
 #ALBK048878001 EN   
 #ACQM679487001 EN

Comment: QA_TABLE_MODULE


  MODULE_ID MODULE_NAME 
 1   LANGUE 
 2   AGE

Comment: QA_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE


 ATTRIBUTE_ID ATTRIBUTE_NAME MODULE_ID 
 1    GERMAN     1 
 2    NGLISH     1 
 3    UNKNOWN     1 
 4    0_17_YO     2 
 5    18_34_YO    2 
 6    35_54_YO    2

Comment: Sorry I don't know a better way to provide sample data in a comment... I'm pretty new to posting here

Comment: Hi,@Fortysixand2, you can provide sample data by editing the content of question.